# How to do aggregation in several columns of a df upon a boolean column?

Tags: python, boolean, aggregation, timedelta

the initial df has 4 columns:

date_time, production_line_no, var1, var2, running. This is a realy common data set for production environment.

date_time is: a time stamp,

production_line_no is: a categorical to identify a production line,

var1, var2 are: numerical,

running: is a boolean to indicate if the production line is running

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'date_time':['2017-03-22 10:07',
                     '2017-03-23 10:08',
                     '2017-03-24 10:09',
                     '2017-03-25 10:10',
                     '2017-03-26 10:11',
                     '2017-03-27 10:12',
                     '2017-03-28 10:13',
                     '2017-03-29 10:14',
                     '2017-03-22 10:15',
                     '2017-03-22 10:16',
                     '2017-03-22 10:17',
                     '2017-03-22 10:18',
                     '2017-03-22 10:19',
                     '2017-03-22 10:20',
                     '2017-03-22 10:21',
                     '2017-03-22 10:22',
                     '2017-03-22 10:23',
                     '2017-03-22 10:24',
                     '2017-03-22 10:25',
                     '2017-03-22 10:26',
                     '2017-03-22 10:27',
                     '2017-03-22 10:28',
                     '2017-03-22 10:29',
                     '2017-03-22 10:30'],
     
        'production_line_no':[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
        'var1':[20, 21, 4, 18, 20, 21, 2, 18, 20, 21, 1, 18, 10, 6, 9, 8, 10, 3, 9, 8, 7, 18, 20, 21], 
        'var2':[20, 21, 19, 18, 20, 21, 19, 18, 20, 21, 19, 18, 10, 11, 9, 8, 10, 11, 9, 8, 19, 18, 20, 21], 
        'running':[0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
       }

df=pd.DataFrame(data)

df
```

[df results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSuXX.png)

I need to do several aggregations along the running cycles times and to get them back into a dataframe that contains the times stamps of the start and end of the running cycles (means running = 1) and the aggregated vars and the production_line_no

final df must looks like this:

start date_time, end_date_time, Time_delta, production_line_no, var1_aggregation_1, var1_aggregation_2, var2_aggregation_1, var2_aggregation_2,....,

```py
data = {'start date_time':['2017-03-22 10:07', '2017-03-22 10:15', '2017-03-22 10:23', '2017-03-22 10:27'],
        'end_date_time':['2017-03-22 10:10','2017-03-22 10:18','2017-03-22 10:26', '2017-03-22 10:30'],     
        'Time_delta':['00:03', '00:03', '00:03', '00:03'],
        'production_line_no':[1, 1, 2, 1],
        'var1_aggregation_1':['value_stdev_var1_cycle1', 'value_stdev_var1_cycle2', 'value_stdev_var1_cycle1', 'value_stdev_var1_cycle3'], 
        'var1_aggregation_2':['value_min_var1_cycle1', 'value_min_var1_cycle2', 'value_min_var1_cycle1', 'value_min_var1_cycle3'], 
        'var2_aggregation_1':['value_stdev_var2_cycle1', 'value_stdev_var2_cycle2', 'value_stdev_var2_cycle1', 'value_stdev_var2_cycle3'], 
        'var2_aggregation_2':['value_min_var2_cycle1', 'value_min_var2_cycle2', 'value_min_var2_cycle1', 'value_min_var2_cycle3'], 

    
       
       }

df1=pd.DataFrame(data)

df1
```

[df1 results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LKl4.png)

For a gain of time I did not calculate the value of the aggregations, but it should be clear I suppose.

Does anyone knows how to achieve it ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I spend some time and I proceeded that way:

first I breakdown the issue in two parts, 1. the cycle identification, 2. the aggregation calculations.

Here is the code that works pretty well, but could certainly be optimized.

```py
# Convert date time string to DateTime type
df['date_time']= pd.to_datetime(df['date_time'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')

# Create cycle_ID to differenciate the different cycles and prepare the use of groupby() + agg()
df['cycle_ID']=df['running'].diff().abs().cumsum()*df['running']

# Define agg type Pandas built-in
aggregations = {
    'var1':['std','min'],
    'var2':['std','min'],
    'date_time':lambda x:(max(x) - min(x)).days
}

# Create the grouped object
grouped=df.groupby(by=['cycle_ID', 'production_line_no'],as_index=False).agg(aggregations)
grouped
```

Here is the result I got

[Final results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/asI1t.png)

How can I make it more robust, or fast ? as it will need to be applied to a large number of rows.

I also would like to be able to extend the aggregation functions to more complex ones more dedicated to time series analysis like integral (area under the curve, or count the number of positive/ negative peaks, value of the inflexion point, ... )

How to extend that analysis by cycle with data visualisation ? Like FacetGrid plot and superposed plots ?
Any advices for that ?

Thx for your inputs.